# dynamic stack impementation-what is wrong with this code? Why i am getting run time error?

Tags: c++, stack

Why am I getting run time error in this code? What is wrong with it? I am new with linked list I am unable to understand why the following code is giving run time error what is wrong with the code? I am trying to implement stack dynamically. Kindly help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct stack
{
    int a ;
    struct stack *n;
};
    typedef struct stack st;
    st *top = new st;
```

// TO INSERT THE ELEMENT

```
 void push(int a)
 {
     st *p;
     p = new st;
     p->n = top;
     top = p;
  }
```

//TO EXTRACT THE ELEMENT

```
     int pop()
     {
    st *p;
    p=top;
    if(top == NULL)
    {
            cout<<"stack is already empty";
 }
 else
 {
    top = top->n;
    return p->a;
    delete p;
 }
     }
    //DISPLAY FUNCTION

void display()
{
    st *p;
    p=top;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
    cout<<p->a;
    p=p->n;
}
cout<<p->a;

}
int main()
{
    push(1);
    push(2);
    push(3);
    push(4);
    push(5);
    display();
    int s=pop();
    cout<<s;
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you manage to type the title correctly but then start shouting in the question body?

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong

```
void display()
{
    st *p;
    p=top;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->a;
        p=p->n;
    }
    cout<<p->a;
}
```

should be

```
void display()
{
    st *p;
    p=top;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->a;
        p=p->n;
    }
}
```

In your version p is NULL after you exit the while loop, so the second `cout<<p->a;` crashes your program.

This code is wrong

```
st *top = new st;
```

it should be

```
st *top = NULL;
```

The rest of your code makes it clear the top == NULL means an empty stack, so you should do `top = NULL;` initially.

Comment: thanks the error is removed but its not taking any value it is just displaying 0 ten times..

Comment: @user2177859 You need to add `p->a = a;` to `push`.